# 98 Mercedes ML 320 - Overheating Issue

Tags: mercedes-benz, overheating, ml320

My car keeps over heating when I get on the freeway. It's fine on city streets. I put antifreeze in it.  It seems like it runs out kind of fast but I havent noticed any leaking.

Answer (score 2):

Overheating on the highway is likely due to a clog in the system, or a pinhole leak.  Since your adding, I would say there is a leak somewhere.  This leak is either going to be a hole in a hose, cracked radiator or leaking gasket (thermostat gasket, head gasket, etc.).  If it is a head gasket, your exhaust will smoke a bit more than normal and will smell like coolant.  I have had several leaks (radiator hose, crack in radiator) that I was only able to see after the engine was overheating.  You want to look for signs of coolant that has sprayed and dried.  Right when you get home from a drive, pop the hood and look for anything wet where coolant might had recently sprayed.  You can also pressurize the coolant system with a radiator pressure tester and watch for leaks.  Another thing you can try is to feel the radiator to see if there are cold spots.  Cold spots mean there is a clog.